# Select latest row from a group of options MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contains a set of options and relevant pricing. We have versioning implemented which means that we store several rows for the same option with different timestamps. Everytime we make an update to the pricing, a new row is created with a timestamp.

I am using the query below:

```
    SELECT 
    localizedOptionID,
    uProfileID,
    sOptionID,
    MAX(datestamp),
    localOptionName,
    quantities
FROM
    localisedProductOptions
WHERE
    uProfileID = 2
    AND sOptionID in ('BGCD','Q6G1','3BET')
GROUP BY sOptionID
ORDER BY MAX(datestamp)
```

It seems to be returning only one version of each row, but unfortunately it does not seem to be the latest.

Can anyone help me setting up the query? All the data is contained within one single table, so I am not using any join.

Comment: Not sure if I'm reading your question correctly but if I am it looks like you just need to alter your ORDER BY statement, try "ORDER BY datestamp DESC"

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not trying to order the results, but rather to return only the latest row within all the results for one given sOptionID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below mentioned query to get desire data

```
    select   localizedOptionID, uProfileID,sOptionID, datestamp,localOptionName, 
quantities from localisedProductOptions WHERE uProfileID = 2  AND sOptionID in 
('BGCD','Q6G1','3BET') and datestamp in(select MAX(datestamp) from
 localisedProductOptions where  uProfileID = 2 AND sOptionID in 
('BGCD','Q6G1','3BET') GROUP BY sOptionID);
```